# Flutter web build release shows white screen

Tags: python, flutter, web, build

First i run `flutter build web --release` in the same location that my pubspec.yaml is, once it is build i do `cd build/web` and then I start a http server with `python -m http.server 5000`. The webpage shows a blank white screen. Then I checked the logs in dev tools and saw these errors:

[image]

`The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/plain').` and `localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:5000/') with script ('http://localhost:5000/flutter_service_worker.js?v=3443120066'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/plain').` are the errors I encounter. How do I fix this?

Here is the console logs from the python server:

```
Serving HTTP on :: port 5000 (http://[::]:5000/) ...
::1 - - [30/Jul/2022 01:01:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [30/Jul/2022 01:01:58] "GET /flutter.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [30/Jul/2022 01:01:59] code 404, message File not found
::1 - - [30/Jul/2022 01:01:59] "GET /requestProvider.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 -
::1 - - [30/Jul/2022 01:01:59] "GET /flutter_service_worker.js?v=3443120066 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [30/Jul/2022 01:02:03] "GET /main.dart.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [30/Jul/2022 01:02:03] "GET /main.dart.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [30/Jul/2022 01:02:04] code 404, message File not found
::1 - - [30/Jul/2022 01:02:04] "GET /main.dart HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```